# Partial string merge between 2 large datasets on R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, merge, text-mining

I have two dataframes, the 1st one contains about 900K observations and 2 columns :

| ID | COMPANY |
| --- | --- |
| AD8.OSZ.23490 | Company1 |
| AD8.OSZ.18903 | Company2 |
| AD8.OSZ.90126 | Company3 |

The second ones contains about 130k observations and also 2 columns, but the ID format is different (but not all observations are in the same form, for some there is no AD8.OSZ. for instance).

| ID | Client_Since |
| --- | --- |
| desr-j50q02-AD8.OSZ.23490 | 1981 |
| desr-j50q02-AD8.OSZ.18903 | 2003 |
| desr-j50q02-AD8.OSZ.90126 | 2018 |

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

| Full_ID | Client_Since | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| desr-j50q02-AD8.OSZ.23490 | 1981 | Company1 |
| desr-j50q02-AD8.OSZ.18903 | 2003 | Company2 |
| desr-j50q02-AD8.OSZ.90126 | 2018 | Company3 |

I tried 2 codes for my left join (i want to keep all the 130k obs) :

```
#1st 

library(fuzzyjoin)

df3 <- df %>% regex_left_join(df2, by = c(Full_ID = "ID"))

#2nd code

library(stringr)

df3 <- df %>% fuzzy_left_join(df2, by = c("Full_ID" = "ID"), match_fun = str_detect)
```

> Error : memory vectors exhausted (limit reached ?)

I think that this code is too weak for the datasets i have / not appropriate for my MacbookAir. I did the manipulation found here : [R on MacOS Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached) but it didn't change anything.

I read about "parallelizing" the use of R (https://datasquad.at.sites.carleton.edu/data/storage-design/dealing-with-a-vector-memory-exhausted-error-in-r/) but i really don't understand how to use mclapply with my join command.

I also looked at that topic : [Partial string merge R large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975268/partial-string-merge-r-large-dataset) but is not exactly the same case as me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way to think of it where from the sample you have shared you always seek IDs after the last period, hence you can create a new column with text after last period and join using it.

Below is example of how you can do that;

```
# Reading required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Create sample dataframes
df1 <-
  data.frame(ID = c("AD8.OSZ.23490", "AD8.OSZ.18903", "AD8.OSZ.90126"),
             COMPANY = c("Company1", "Company2", "Company3"))

df2 <-
  data.frame(ID = c("desr-j50q02-AD8.OSZ.23490", "desr-j50q02-AD8.OSZ.18903", "desr-j50q02-AD8.OSZ.90126"),
             Client_Since = c("1981", "2003", "2018"))

# Modify first dataframe
mod_df1 <-
  df1 %>%
  # Get characters after last period
  mutate(MOD_ID = sub('.*\\.', '', ID))

# Modify second dataframe
mod_df2 <-
  df2 %>%
  # Get characters after last period
  mutate(MOD_ID = sub('.*\\.', '', ID))

# Join tables
mod_df1 %>%
  left_join(mod_df2, by = c("MOD_ID"))
```